# How to remove dependency from whole project

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I need to remove `support-v4` dependency from whole project. For this I add next code to gradle file:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

But after clean and apk rebuild i still see `support-v4` methods.

What I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tryed removing the dependency line for this module in your project's gradle.build file ?

Comment: sure i have remove it.

Comment: Then i don't really know, tought it was still good to point that out, just in case your forgot about it !

Comment: i mention that it's exist while i have 'support-v7' dependency... but event exclude does not help...

Comment: Is _support-v4_ still showing up in the output of `gradle dependencies`?